# CodeIgniter resize() problem

Tags: codeigniter, resize

Function:

```
function do_upload() {

    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();


    $config = array( 
        'image_library' => 'gd2', 
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'], 
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 267
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    $this->image_lib->clear();

}
```

And gives a white page, dont display errors.
**But if I erase this lines, works fine!**

```
'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
'width' => 150,
'height' => 26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your system have the gd2 library installed?

Is there anything in the log files?

Comment: The problem was that the image I was used are with the extension .JPG in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

problem is because you dont have **create_thumb = TRUE**

try forming an array this way. its cleaner and error free.

```
public function resize($path, $file){
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $path;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 280;
        $config['height'] = 165;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/'.$file;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
```